# Update ContentVersion custom field by user with Salesforce Platform license

Tags: permissions, files, contentversion, licenses

I have ContentVersion record with custom field Status__c. I have apex code updating Status__c field. It is working correctly if I use user with **Salesforce** license.

The updating user **is not owner** of ContentVersion record.

I changed license of user to **Salesforce Platform** and I got error "*INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.*"

I understand that I need grant update permission to user who is not owner and trying to update.

Question1 : Is it possible to make it working by user with **Salesforce Platform** license or there is no chance to be able to update Status__c field by user with this license?

Question2: If user with **Salesforce Platform** license can update ContentVersion.Status__c (custom field) field in terms of license, what permissions shall I set?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a sharing issue. Is your Apex class with or without sharing?

Comment: You should post your issues as part of the question then self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION I found:** I needed to fix 2 points. My code flow is ContentVersion--> ContentDoc --> ContentDocumentTriggerHandler --> update of XYZ__c. I did not have Edit permission for XYZ__c object for user with **Salesforce Platform** license + I needed to set ContentDocumentLink.ShareType=I for ContentDocumentLink record with LinkedEntityId related to XYZ__c. This way I am able to share ContentDocument based on ShareType set on ContentDocumentLink record. My XYZ__c has Edit permission and I can now edit ContentVersion custom field because ContentDocumentLink has set ShareType=I.